# Merging objects fields in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I tried many solutions with "mongodb aggregation", but without good solutions.
If you have any solutions, thanks for yours help.

I have a document which looks like this:

```
 {  
    "id" : 1,
    "sales" : {
      "1": {
        "count": 200,
        "A": {
            "count": 1,
        },
        "B": {
            "count": 2,
        }
        ...     
    },
     "2": {
        "count": 200,
        "A2": {
            "count": 1,
        },
        "B2": {
            "count": 2,
        }
        ...     
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "sales" : {
      "1": {
        "count": 200,
        "A": {
            "count": 1,
        },
        "B": {
            "count": 2,
        }
        ...     
    },
     "2": {
        "count": 200,
        "A2": {
            "count": 1,
        },
        "B2": {
            "count": 2,
        }
        ...     
}
```

I want to group by count and the number of instances of "sales" and "refs". 
Something like this:

```
{
    "sales" : [
    {
        "title" : "1",
        "count" : 400,
        "refs" : [
            {
                "ref" : "A",
                "count" : 2
            },
            {
                "ref" : "B",
                "count" : 4
            }               
        ]
    },
    {
        "title" : "2",
        "count" : 400,
        "refs" : [
            {
                "ref" : "A2",
                "count" : 2
            },
            {
                "ref" : "B2",
                "count" : 4
            }               
        ]
    }       
]
```

}

Robert
**** XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX ****